# Why google doesn't index youtube videos in sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap, video

I've created a sitemap for youtube hosted videos in my website. you can find it here.
http://www.informaincasa.it/wp-content/uploads/sitemap-video.xml

I've also created a sitemap for videos hosted on blip.tv

The first sitemap while webmasters tool says it has no error isn't indexed. The second one is.

Do you know why this happens and what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

When submitting a sitemap to Google that contains links on more than one domain you need to have added each of those domains to your Webmaster Tools account, and verified each.

If you have not added and verified it Google will only index links on the domain that the sitemap is hosted on.

Since you do not own or control the other domains you are asking about Google is just ignoring those links in your sitemap.

On this page https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75712 it says:

If you have multiple websites, you can simplify the process of creating and submitting Sitemaps by creating one or more Sitemaps that includes URLs for all your verified sites, and saving the Sitemap(s) to a single location. All sites must be verified in Webmaster Tools.

This process implicitly proves to Google that you own all the sites involved. Cross-site submissions will work only if all sites have been verified in Webmaster Tools.

To host cross-site Sitemaps in a single location:

- Make sure that you have verified ownership of all sites.
- Create a Sitemap that includes URLs from all the sites that you want to cover. You can create a single Sitemap that includes URLs from all sites or you can create one or more separate Sitemaps for each site.
- Using Google Webmaster Tools, submit your Sitemap(s).

Answer (score 1):

I see people here say you need to own the host/have it on your Webmaster. 
In my experience that is not true.

I have a site with 5 youtube iframe videos and submitted a videositemap using this guide:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/sitemaps

No errors, and currently 2 of 5 videos are indexed.

As a sidenote, I also have marked them up uing schema.org like this:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/schema

> Google recommends using the schema.org on-page markup for videos. The schema.org vocabulary was developed and is supported by Google, Bing, and Yahoo! Using schema.org to describe your videos will allow Google to index and show your videos in search.

Answer (score 0):

In these situation what seems to me the possible cause is that google already knows about the content added to the youtube, as it owns it.
It must be searching for the content of the page that is related to the youtube video on your site.
Rather than worrying about the video I would suggest you to check the content of the pages of your website.